# Jquery Enabling and disabling Link Click event using .on or .off

Tags: jquery

Trying to disable/enable click event on a hyperlink.

Found some result from the google search, that by using `.on` or `.off` can do the job.

Bascillay I want to do like, on click of a link do some ajax call , until ajax call is not complete disable the link then after ajax enable it back.

But My bad not able to achieve the same.

Have create a fiddle and link http://jsfiddle.net/Ta6cX/

Please correct me what's going wrong in my code that its not enabling back.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#testOnOff').on('click', function (e){
    $(this).removeAttr("href","");
    if(e.target != e.currentTarget) {   
        $('#msg').text("donr"+(i++));
    }    

});

$('#test').on('click', function (e){
    $('#testOnOff').attr('href',"#");
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ta6cX/4/)

Comment: Sorry @Alek, Its not helping, I have updated your version http://jsfiddle.net/Ta6cX/4/ , on click of the same element its triggering click event

Comment: @Jayaram Pradhan post your ajax call please.

Comment: I think you have to make changes on success and just before ajax call :) @Jayaram Pradhan